# Java way to name methods to execute a query

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data

I'm working on school during quarantaine and on the weekly bases my teacher checks my progress. Now in the last meeting he told me it's good to use queries like this*, **but** there is a better way. He told me you can name a method in a way so it will execute the query for you (without actually making the query). He than emailed me a link to look at (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods). The problem is, it's so much text and I don't even know the term I have to look up to get to know more about it. I only need a 100% and this site gives me a 1000% so I'm really confused on where to look. Does anybody know the term he described?

*in the JPA-Repository:

```
 @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.house.houseId = ?1")
 List<Person> getPeopleFromHouse(long houseId);
```

Maybe query-methods?

Comment: Read this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he wants you to use : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions

Assume a Person has an Address with a ZipCode. In that case, the method creates the property traversal x.address.zipCode. The resolution algorithm starts by interpreting the entire part (AddressZipCode) as the property and checks the domain class for a property with that name (uncapitalized). If the algorithm succeeds, it uses that property

Answer (score 1):

He is suggesting that you use JPA repositories. Once your custom repository extends `JpaRepository`, you now have different methods available, like `getOne`, which returns an instance by the ID that you pass in.

Hopefully the code below will give you a starting point.

House:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class House {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
}
```

HouseRepository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface HouseRepository extends JpaRepository<House, Integer> {

}
```